# how to prevent from spammers while submitting web form in asp.net?

Tags: .net, validation, spam-prevention

i am working on a project developed in **asp.net**. In that one page holds the order details. Validation works well while form values filled up normally but some spammers are by pass that validations (All validations are done from client-side).

For example, i have one dropdown as "ProductName" and default value is "Please Select Product" and it is required field validator (validation on client-side only), but for some reason some spammers are by pass validation with that default selected value "Please Select Product".

It looks somthing like this:

```
ProductId: 1
ProductName: Please Select Product <== here it must be a product name
Address: As Specified Above
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should have [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) implemented on every input form page available to Un-Authenticated/Public Users.

secondly, you should validate your inputs on server side as well.
in ASP.Net with `Page.IsValid`  and in MVC.Net `ModelState.IsValid`